Vite - Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist
I have this problem when using Vite.
I get this message on the console.
[These are the folders] (https://i.sstatic.net/nK8XtQPN.png)
I use Microsoft Edge, have the console with Git-bash, run npm install, and then npm run dev. After that, I open the dev tools and see that message.
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
Thank you very much in advance.

Try rebooting or re-install dependencies
